# Joomla Trouble strtotime()

Tags: php, joomla

Something weird hapend with joomla... can somebody help me?

This is the error:

Warning: strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Santiago' for 'CLST/-3.0/DST' instead in /home/fundacio/public_html/libraries/joomla/utilities/date.php on line 56

This is the site: www.fundacioncasadelafamilia.cl

Comment: No one is going to go to a random website; post your code instead.

Comment: Well I just went onto it. If you don't want to go on it - that's fine - but stop trying to speak for everyone thankyou. I know it's SO rules to post code rather than sites but you can politely tell that to a first time user and not be so rude about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a PHP change, not a Joomla change. PHP 5.3.0 needs the date.timezone ini entry setting properly in order to avoid the warning being sent out. Prior to PHP 5.3.0, the line existed in the PHP ini but was generally commented out.

If you cannot get your hosts to change this you could also add in in the index.php file of the main Joomla installation or in a template file:

```
date.timezone = "America/Anchorage"
```

however this would get overridden on Joomla updates so the php.ini change is preferable! Also if it is a hosting issue I suspect many of the hosts clients will be seeing this message!!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In joomla we have an option to set the default time zone in back end (administrator section)
Set their your required zone and use the code below to set that in php

```
//setting the default time zone
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
date_default_timezone_set($config->getValue('config.offset'));
```

This code can be placed inside your root/includes/framework or any root level file 
It will override everywhere.

Hope this will help you..

Comment: Remember though by adding code into Joomla root/framework/includes etc. etc. That they will be overridden on Joomla updates. So php.ini is a better solution!

Comment: Yes thats right, but we have admin option available to set this,So php.ini change will not update from admin side .

Comment: True but it shouldn't matter. This Joomla bug tracker report (http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=19421) suggests setting it in php.ini - so I can't see it being an issue. I assume Joomla also corrects for the timezone at a later point!